# can the same function argument accept different data types?

Tags: javascript, types, arguments

Sorry for the simple question. I have this function:

```
function(var1){ 
    var myString =var1;
    //  myString is parsed for integers 
}
```

Is it necessary to always call the argument as a string?  e.g.

```
function("23")
```

Or can I safely mix and match? e.g.

```
function(23);
function("string with number 23");
```

Comment: Javascript is dynamically typed... maybe time to start with a good book?

Comment: Could you tell us what is in the function?

Comment: @Kerrek: The last online guide I read said to pass the correct data type. I think that was just good practice rather than required by the language, foe the reason you give. but I needed to make sure.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - it isn't written yet! I am writing a function that takes the argument "bookname-chapter_pagenumber". The string is then parsed for its three elements. But 99 times out of 100 "bookname-chapter" are unchanged. It would be extremely convenient to just type a number in most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass different data types as Javascript is dynamically typed language.
if you want a different behavior depending on the data type, you may use `instanceof`.

Like this:

```
function f(var1) {
    if(var1 instanceof String) {
        // handle strings
    } else if(var1 instanceof Object) {
        // handle objects
    } else if(var1 instanceof Date) {
        // handle dates
    }
}
```

This can also be used to filter/validate the input data.

**Update:** please note @jakeclarkson's comment regarding the difference between `instanceof` and `typeof` operators.

Comment: Thanks. That is perfect. I was going to use typeOf but instanceOf looks better.

Comment: Beware that this will not work with `String` literals, e.g. `"a string" instanceof String` will return `false` whereas `new String("a string") instanceof String` will return `true`. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/32shh/).

Comment: +1 to @jakeclarkson. `instanceof` and `typeof` are similar but not the same. Their usage depends on the project architecture and the type of the issue. I'll reference that comment in the initial reply.

Comment: If you're able to use 3rd party code in your application you might want to consider [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/); it has all of the wrapper methods you'll need to detect input's type.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass whatever datatype you want to a function. It just matters how you use the arguments.

Comment: Many thanks. I just needed to make sure - as not every browser is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix and match - as long as your integer parser is setup to work with the mixture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either way if you want the number to be a int and do some kind of math do not put in speech marks.

If you do pass a number as a string you can allways use

```
parseInt("string");
```

Answer (score 1):

**short answer: YES**

**Long answer:** Type checking is a real pain in JavaScript. This only gets harder if you start trying to differentiate arrays and objects.

I would use Crockford's typeOf function which can be found [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html)

However if you only plan on passing in strings or numbers this should do:

```
function (var1) {
   if (typeof var1 === "number"){
     //treat it like a number
   } else if (typeof var1 === "string") {
     //try to parse it
   } else {
     //Its neither a string nor a number
   }
}
```